# How can I order_by using difference in annotation Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models which refer to a third
The 1st one:

```
class question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('tag',related_name='tgs')
    publicationMoment = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    authorId = models.ForeignKey('user',on_delete=models.PROTECT,default = 1)
    objects=questionManager()
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'
```

And 2 objects that refer to question:

```
class upvoteQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('question',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class downvoteQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('question',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to sort questions by difference of number of entries like this:

```
class questionManager(models.Manager):


    def orderByRating(self):
        return question.objects.annotate(
            likes = Count('upvotequestion'),
            dis = Count('downvotequestion')
            ).annotate(
            rat = F('likes')-F('dis')
            ).order_by(
            '-rat','-publicationMoment'
            )
```

I tried this:

```
class questionManager(models.Manager):


    def orderByRating(self):
        return question.objects.annotate(rat = Count('upvotequestion')-Count('downvotequestion')).order_by('-rat','-publicationMoment')
```

and this:

```
def orderByRating(self):
        return question.objects.annotate(rat = F('upvotequestion')-F('downvotequestion')).order_by('-rat','-publicationMoment')
```

But it still doesn't work

Comment: How do you *use* the manager?

Comment: Like @WillemVanOnsem asked, how do you use it? Also, instead of `return question.objects.annotate... ` should be `return self.annotate....`.

Comment: @foobarna  , thanks, I’ve fixed. But it still doesn’t work

Comment: @GlebMakarenko: but you still didn't show any view, etc. where you demonstrate *how* you are using the manager...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `def hot(request):
    return render(request,'listing.html',{'page_obj':paginate(question.objects.orderByRating(),request,4),
                                          'pagename':'Hot questions',
                                          'linkname':'New Questions',
                                          'link':'main'}
                                          )` Here is view

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Here is paginate `def paginate(obj_list, request, per_page=1):

    paginator=Paginator(obj_list,per_page)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')

    page_obj=paginator.get_page(page_number)
    
    return page_obj`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If I try code I showed it will work but sorting will be incorrect

Comment: You might be able to get Django's ORM to do this, but performance is going to suck. Doing this means that every time `orderByRating` is called, your SQL server need to load and count every upvote that has been issued, in order to determine what order to return the posts in. I would suggest denormalizing your data a little by storing a score for each question, and recalculating that score when someone leaves an upvote or downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of bad modeling. Indeed, you make two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s which means that the votes will act as a "multiplier" of each other, and both upvotes and downvotes will be equivalent. You can fix this with:

```
class questionManager(models.Manager):
    def order_by_rating(self):
        return (
            question.objects.annotate(
                likes=Count('upvotequestion', distinct=True),
                dis=Count('downvotequestion', distinct=True),
            )
            .annotate(rat=F('likes') - F('dis'))
            .order_by('-rat', '-publicationMoment')
        )
```

But this is just fixing problem at the wrong place. The modeling even allows a user to both upvote and downvote the same item.

You can make a simple vote system:

```
from django.conf import settings


class QuestionVote(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(choices=[(1, 'up'), (-1, 'down')], default=1)
```

Then you can for example order this by:

```
class questionManager(models.Manager):
    def order_by_rating(self):
        return self.alias(rat=Sum('questionvote__score')).order_by(
            '-rat', '-publicationMoment'
        )
```

You can also include likes and dislikes with:

```
class questionManager(models.Manager):
    def order_by_rating(self):
        return (
            self.annotate(
                likes=Count('questionvote', filter=Q(questionvote__score__gt=0)),
                dislikes=Count(
                    'questionvote', filter=Q(questionvote__score__lt=0)
                ),
            )
            .alias(rat=Sum('questionvote__type'))
            .order_by('-rat', '-publicationMoment')
        )
```